Glue job uses workers unnecessarily
I'm running a sample glue job. The main function is as below:
    locations = ['Singapore', 'Australia', 'Brazil'] 
    # Process tables in parallel using Spark's parallelize method
    sc.parallelize(locations).foreach(
        lambda location: process_locations(
            location=location
        )
    )

    # Commit the job bookmarks after processing all tables
    job.commit()

The process_locations is straightforward, just to print out the location:
def process_locations(location): 
    print(location)

The code works fine and does print out locations as expected. However, I noticed some strange behaviour when I play around with the maximum number of workers of the glue job.

As indicated in the screen capture, I'm running Glue 4.0 and aws console says AWS Glue will optimize costs and resource usage by dynamically scaling the number of workers up and down throughout the job run. Given that I only have 3 locations in the list, so I was expecting to utilise 4 workers (3 executers + 1 driver). However, when I exam the log files, I saw 15 log files, 3 of which contains the printed message and the remaining 11 simply starts a worker and then exits.
I tried to reduce the max number of workers to 2, glue job this time only generated 2 log files, 1 for driver and 1 for executer, but only 1 location get printed out.
My question here:

Did I mis-understand something about the Automatically Scale feature of glue job?
When I reduce the workers to 2, what did I do wrong to cause glue job to miss out in printing the other 2 locations?

Appreciate any advice!
